# Float two divs on the right, one on top of each other

Tags: html, css

All
this is my first stack overflow post, thanks in advance for any help

I am putting together a page with content and divs with image background, when I try to float two divs on the right one on top of each other, having trouble flow content to the left, I have used clear so one div is on top of the other one on the right, but the content I am trying to put on the left is align with the second image where the clear was applied then there is a big gap for the first div, any suggestions?

I have enclosed code here

```
.img1 {
float: right;
width: 250px;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #cccccc;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid #f5aca6;
background: url("url") no-repeat 50% 10px;
background-color: #ffecec;
padding: 70px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.img2 {
float: right;
background: url("url")no-repeat 100% 100%;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 30px;
background-color: #006534; 
color: #d2d2d2;
line-height: 20px;
font-size: 13px;
width: 250px;
border: thin silver solid;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #cccccc;
padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img1">content</div>
<p class="clear"></p>
<div class="img2">content</div>
<div>Content.........</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: as @j08691 said, please post the code you have tried. The clear will make it so that anything in the markup "below" the clear will display "below" whatever floats have been cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I believe it's what you asked for:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float: left;">
<div>Content.........</div>
</div>

<div style="float: right;">
<div class="img1">content</div>
<br>
<div class="img2">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img1 {
width: 250px;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #cccccc;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid #f5aca6;
background: url("url") no-repeat 50% 10px;
background-color: #ffecec;
}

.img2 {
background: url("url")no-repeat 100% 100%;
background-color: #006534; 
color: #d2d2d2;
line-height: 20px;
font-size: 13px;
width: 250px;
border: thin silver solid;
box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #cccccc;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmzwLn2q/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have modified however the content is now below both img divs, and I have reversed the order, the content is above both img divs, any thoughts?

Comment: judging from the symptom you describe, you most likely forgot to add `float: left` to the content (or better put, the content container).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, I have added the float left, the content is across the page where the img divs are either on top of to the right it or below to the right, depend on the order of code

Comment: all, I have set a width for the content so the img could move up but the content is not wrapping the imge at the bottom, any ideas?

Comment: it seems the float left is not really working for the content part I have setup width for it so it come up, then there is space below the img div if the content goes too long.